# Announcement: minor edits to the Ask Different Tour

Tags: discussion, site-scope, close-reasons, tour

First off - thanks for doing your parts in an excellent 2023 here in the community of asking for help and learning together while using Apple products and services. Everyone on meta, doing moderation work, showing up and commenting on the main site is very much appreciated.

On to the announcement:

- I’ve made some minor changes to the [Ask Different Tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour)

Specifically, I cleaned up the “what’s on topic” to be less wordy. The site is about Apple hardware, Apple software, Apple services and third party tools that relate to the three categories of Apple products.

Secondly, I reworked the “**These might seem on-topic but are not:**” section based on discussions here on meta, flags the elected moderators discussed and handled as well as comments everyone made from 2023.

I moved the “programming” section to the end as it rambles the most and we get the most feedback on that item.

I clarified the unlawful / unlicensed wording, but the intent hasn’t changed. Nothing else was intended to change our policy, but I wanted the page to read more easily, have less jargon and reflect the decisions made in the past on what we allow scripting and programming and Xcode-wise.

Please answer if you have suggestions / comments or found a typo I have made. Suggestions on clarity of that page are always welcome here or in flags when you run into an interesting question you feel illustrates our guidelines documented on [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) and in the help section.

Answer (score 2):

> Questions with many possible answers (vote for the best, list all) or that which require extremely long answers

Grammatically, '…or those which…' or just '…or which…' would sit easier with me.

> Shopping or buying recommendations for hardware, accessories like bags and cases. Questions that are mainly about price are considered "shopping" questions.

Maybe '…for software or hardware, or accessories…'
I'm also not sure price should be a consideration, otherwise people will argue, "I was looking for freeware".

*After comments - version 2…*

> Shopping or buying recommendations for software or hardware, accessories like bags and cases, or questions asking "Which is the best…?"

Here are some relevant questions which we can use to evaluate “shopping” wording:

- [What is the cheapest way to get windows running on a Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/45400/5472)

Comment: I’m leaning towards “or which”. The second item, I want to say that if a question mentions price (free, or any number) then it’s likely to be closed or edited as that’s a key indicator of shopping. How does that second part fit your reading of the intention?

Comment: @bmike - I prefer "or which" too. I added a possible version 2, trying to cover all bases without mentioning purchase or price specifically.

Comment: Understood, let’s put up a few shopping related questions to make sure we’re all set before we edit again.